# How to talk to Kafka KUDO Internal Setup?

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I have Kafka setup via KUDO:

```
https://kudo.dev/docs/runbooks/kafka/external-access.html#internal-access
```

KUDO Kafka has a headless service.

How do I go about creating topics for kafka?

I have installed kafkacat CLI tool:

```
https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat
```

I tried to port forward a borker IP from the server to my local machine:

```
kubectl -n kafka port-forward kf-kafka-0 9092
```

Port forwarding works, but issuing a kafkacat command fails:

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092  -C -t test
% ERROR: Topic test error: Broker: Leader not available
```

Is there some other tool I can install that allows me to create topics and test if a message is in that topic.

The only other way I though of was actually deploying a service on k8s that produces a message, and check the events of the pod for errors

Any way to get kafkacat to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer:

Use kubefwd CLI